# Python xlwings fails to run COM server

Tags: python, xlwings

I’m a stumped.  Xlwings is reporting failure to activate the COM server.  I am using Excel 365 on Windows 10 and xlwings 0.17.1 (Excel module version 0.20.5) and using a python 3.8 conda environment crated directly through Anaconda Navigator.

In Excel, I traced the error to a shell command (below), which is kicked off by Excel XLPyCommand() in the xlwings Module (xlwings quickstart myproject --standalone).

```
cmd.exe /K ""C:\Users\Chris\anaconda3\condabin\conda" activate xw_cja && pythonw -B -c "import sys, os;sys.path[0:0]=os.path.normcase(os.path.expandvars(r'D:\Code\Python\AnacondaVenvs\xw_cja;D:\Code\Python\AnacondaVenvs\xw_cja\advena_xw.zip;C:\Users\Chris\anaconda3\envs\xw_cja')).split(';');import xlwings.server; xlwings.server.serve('$(CLSID)')"
```

I created a simple .py file to run this in PyCharm directly.  I replaced “('$(CLSID)')” with “(‘{506e67c3-55b5-48c3-a035-eed5deea7d6d}’)”, which is hard-coded by the developer in both the Excel VBA and the python code.

```
import sys, os
os.path.expandvars(r'D:\Code\Python\AnacondaVenvs\xw_cja;D:\Code\Python\AnacondaVenvs\xw_cja\advena_xw.zip;C:\Users\Chris\anaconda3\envs\xw_cja')
sys.path[0:0]=os.path.normcase(os.path.expandvars(r'D:\Code\Python\AnacondaVenvs\xw_cja;D:\Code\Python\AnacondaVenvs\xw_cja\advena_xw.zip;C:\Users\Chris\anaconda3\envs\xw_cja')).split(';')
import xlwings.server
xlwings.server.serve('{506e67c3-55b5-48c3-a035-eed5deea7d6d}')
```

The code above runs just fine in a standalone ‘.py’ file (in PyCharm).

FYI: I used MKLINK -j (in a batch file) to make a directory junction link C:\Users\Chris\anaconda3\envs to D:\Code\Python\AnacondaVenvs, which makes them synonyms.  This is unrelated, but wihtout this knowledge, you may mistakenly observe path discrepancies in the code above.  (As an aside, I do this to make data on my D drive appear to be on C to manage the space on C)

The shell opened, showing the command is run against the correct conda environment, xw_cja.

Excel hourglassed for at least a minute. Then, I got this error: "Could not activate Python COM server, hr = -2147221164 1000"

I opened a command prompt and ran the following with no errors.
C:\Users\Chris>"C:\Users\Chris\anaconda3\condabin\conda" activate xw_cja

```
(xw_cja) C:\Users\Chris>pythonw -B -c "import sys, os;sys.path[0:0]=os.path.normcase(os.path.expandvars(r'D:\Code\Python\AnacondaVenvs\xw_cja;D:\Code\Python\AnacondaVenvs\xw_cja\advena_xw.zip;C:\Users\Chris\anaconda3\envs\xw_cja\')).split(';')

(xw_cja) C:\Users\Chris>pythonw -B -c "import xlwings.server"

(xw_cja) C:\Users\Chris>pythonw -B -c "import xlwings.server.serve('$(CLSID)')"

(xw_cja) C:\Users\Chris>pythonw -B -c "import sys, os;sys.path[0:0]=os.path.normcase(os.path.expandvars(r'D:\Code\Python\AnacondaVenvs\xw_cja;D:\Code\Python\AnacondaVenvs\xw_cja\advena_xw.zip;C:\Users\Chris\anaconda3\envs\xw_cja\')).split(';');import xlwings.server; xlwings.server.serve('$(CLSID)')"

(xw_cja) C:\Users\Chris>
```

I opened a new command prompt / shell and tried the full command as a single line with no error reported.

```
C:\Users\Chris>"C:\Users\Chris\anaconda3\condabin\conda" activate xw_cja && pythonw -B -c "import sys, os;sys.path[0:0]=os.path.normcase(os.path.expandvars(r'D:\Code\Python\AnacondaVenvs\xw_cja;D:\Code\Python\AnacondaVenvs\xw_cja\advena_xw.zip;C:\Users\Chris\anaconda3\envs\xw_cja\')).split(';');import xlwings.server; xlwings.server.serve()

(xw_cja) C:\Users\Chris>
```

Here is my config data as set on the 'xlwings.conf' worksheet (yes, I removed the leading underscore).

Interpreter_Win pythonw
PYTHONPATH  C:\Users\Chris\anaconda3\envs\xw_cja\
Conda Path  C:\Users\Chris\anaconda3
Conda Env   xw_cja
UDF Modules advena_xw;udf
Debug UDFs  FALSE
Log File
Use UDF Server  FALSE
Show Console    FALSE

Answer (score 1):

So, this was very interesting.  I was using a conda environment.  Even so, adding the anaconda path variables to my system environment variables (Windows 10) resolved the issue.  it is my understanding from the xlwings documentation that this is not needed.  But it resolved my problem.  I did verify that, for most python scripts triggered from Excel, xlwings is using the conda environment.  However, I must have the same version of xlwings dll files in both the conda environment and the main python installation.  I have not had this problem when using venv in the past (the native python virtual environment library).

Comment: Hi Chris (@cadvena): thank you for documenting this. Just to make sure that I have got this right (I have to get IT to make changes to system environment variables), do I only need the following env variable:  
CONDA PATH    :    C:\Users\Chris\anaconda3 _(or rather my equivalent)_  

Or do I need to add PYTHONPATH and some other system environment variables? NB I am using the python module with the same name as the spreadsheet.

Comment: @Diomedea, first, did you try editing your user environment variables?  Even if system variables are blocked, you can likely edit user environment variables. Second, it doesn't matter what variable you edit as long as (1) it contains the path to your system python installation and (2) that variable is in your PATH variable. For example, let's say I have a variable named COLOR with value "c:\blue;c:\red". Then, I place ";%COLOR%" at the end of my PATH variable. In effect PATH now contains the value of COLOR. It is PATH that is important.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes - I did try that and then I got IT to change the system environment variables, but without success. I can use a different approach to sharing functions, so no need to worry about this.